# Set files chosen in jFileChooser as a string?

Tags: java, swing

I want to set files chosen inside a jFileChooser as a string for a stringbuilder segment, but, in a specific pattern. I.e.

```
        {
            sb.append(" -file").append(mods);
        }
```

And "mods" is the file and between each file is a " -file" for example, if I select file1.wad, file2.wad, and file3.pk3, then the desired output to the program would be

```
-file file1.wad -file file2.wad -file file3.pk3
```

How do I do this?

EDIT Here's more of my code. Where exactly would the code Paco Abato suggested go? because at the bottom of the code it spits out loads of errors.

```
private void RunGameButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    String PlayerCount = PlayerCountHere.getText();
    String HostIP = HostIPHere.getText();
    //String MapWarp = MapWarpBox.getName();
    try
    {
        //Basic game launching command.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("cmd.exe /C start C:\\mygame\\game.exe");
        if(NoMonstersBox.isSelected())
        {
            //Add the No Monsters Flag
            sb.append(" -nomonsters");
        }
        if(CheatsBox.isSelected())
        {
            //Add the Cheats Flag
            sb.append(" +SV_CHEATS 1");
        }
        if(Netmode0Button.isSelected())
        {
            //Add Netmode 0 Flag
            sb.append(" -netmode 0");
        }
        if(Netmode1Button.isSelected())
        {
            //Add Netmode 1 Flag
            sb.append(" -netmode 1");
        }
        if(DeathmatchButton.isSelected())
        {
            //Add the Deathmatch Flag
            sb.append(" -deathmatch");
        }
        if(CoopButton.isSelected())
        {
            //Add the Co-op Flag
            sb.append(" -coop");
        }
        if(Skill1Button.isSelected())
        {
            //Add the Skill 1 Flag
            sb.append(" -skill 1");
        }
        if(Skill2Button.isSelected())
        {
            //Add the Skill 2 Flag
            sb.append(" -skill 2");
        }
        if(Skill3Button.isSelected())
        {
            //Add the Skill 3 Flag
            sb.append(" -skill 3");
        }
        if(Skill4Button.isSelected())
        {
            //Add the Skill 4 Flag
            sb.append(" -skill 4");
        }
        if(Skill5Button.isSelected())
        {
            //Add the Skill 5 Flag
            sb.append(" -skill 5");
        }
        if(HostButton.isSelected())
        {
            //Add the Host Flag and add the Player Count from the box
            sb.append(" -host ").append(PlayerCount);
        }
        if(JoinButton.isSelected())
        {
            //Add the Join Flag and add the Host IP from the box
            sb.append(" -join ").append(HostIP);
        }
        //Launch the game
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sb.toString());
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        //Log Error
    }
}
```

Comment: Iterate over the files you selected, and either add 'file.path()' (canonical/absolute/...) or add 'file.name()'
This is not correct code, just to give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

It's as easy as:

```
for (File file : selectedFiles) {
    sb.append(" -file ").append(file.getName());
}
```

Comment: Wait, so where does this go? (noob question)
Because the stringbuilder is in a seperate section from the file selection dialogue.
I'll edit my post with my code. One sec

Comment: You need to store the selected files (or maybe the built string) in an accesible place by your code. There are plenty of alternatives.